# Suppose $A , B , C$ are arbitrary sets and we know that $( A \times B ) \cap ( C \times D ) = \emptyset$ What conclusion can we draw?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. $( A \cap C ) \times ( B \cap D ) = \emptyset$
2. $B \cap D = \emptyset$
3. $A \cap C = \emptyset$
4. $A \cap D = \emptyset$

I feel like answers $2,3$ and $4$ could be correct. For example by substituting $A=C=\emptyset$, or substituting $B=D=\emptyset$, or substituting $A=D=\emptyset$.

Please help!

Comment: Do not confuse $P\implies Q$ with $Q\implies P$.  You are asked what $(A\times B)\cap (C\times D) =\emptyset$ will *always* imply.  You are not asked which of the following could also simultaneously happen (*but might not always necessarily happen*) along with your hypothesis.

Comment: Answers 2,3,4 are all very obviously false.  By letting $A=\emptyset, B=C=D=\{1\}$ you still have the hypothesis is true while $2$ is false.  By letting instead $B=\emptyset, A=C=D=\{1\}$ you have the hypothesis is true while $3,4$ are both false, showing that the implication $(A\times B)\cap (C\times D)=\emptyset \implies B\cap D=\emptyset$ is false as well as replacing the conclusion with that of (3) and (4)

Comment: As for (1)... try an element-chasing argument to see if you can successfully show that $(A\cap C)\times (B\cap D)\subseteq (A\times B)\cap (C\times D)$

Comment: thank you so much!! i get it now

Answer (score 1):

$(A\times B)\cap(C\times D)=\emptyset\implies$

$\forall (a,b) \in (A\times B), (a,b)\notin (C\times D) \implies$

$\neg[(a\in A \land a\in C) \land (b\in B \land b\in D)]\implies$

$\neg (a\in A \land a\in C) \lor \neg (b\in B \land b\in D)\implies$

$(a\notin A \lor a\notin C)\lor(b\notin B\lor b\notin D)$

Since $a\in A \land b\in B$, $(A\times B)\cap(C\times D)\implies a\notin C \lor b\notin D$

$a\notin C \lor b\notin D\implies \neg(a\in C \land b\in D)\implies$

$(A\cap C = \emptyset) \lor (B\cap D=\emptyset)\implies$

$(A\cap C)\times (B\cap D) = \emptyset$

It is not necessarily true that both $A\cap C = \emptyset$ and $B\cap D=\emptyset$.  Only one or the other must be.  From this it follows that $(A\cap C)\times (B\cap D) = \emptyset$ is always true.

For case of $A\cap D = \emptyset$, consider $(a,b) \in (A\times B)$, such that $ (a,b)\notin (C\times D)$.  This does not imply that $a\notin D$.  It just means $a\notin C$ or $b\notin D$.

Answer (score 0):

Only $(1)$ is true.

Start proving by contradiction. If possible let $(A\cap C)\times (B\cap D)\neq \emptyset$ and $(x,y)\in(A\cap C)\times (B\cap D)$. Then show that $(x,y)\in (A\times B)\cap(C\times D)$.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct, because in fact, $(A \times B) \cap (C \times D)$ $=(A \cap C) \times (B \cap D)$ for **any** four sets $A,B,C$ and $D$.